# PHP Fatal error: Unknown typehint

Tags: php, yii, php-5.5

```
public function evaluateExpression($_expression_,$_data_=array())
    {
        if(is_string($_expression_))
        {
            extract($_data_);
            return eval('return '.$_expression_.';');
        }
        else
        {
            $_data_[]=$this;
            return call_user_func_array($_expression_, $_data_);
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error on the first line of this method. I don't see any typehinting here. This above code is from Yii Framework's internal files. (yiilite.php:L842)

The error is intermittent and restarting apache fixes it. Unable to reproduce the error as well. What can cause this issue ? Unable to figure this out.

One thing to note recently this error only happened on Pages using Cache. Earlier it would happen on every page.

We are using memcached and opcache ( PHP 5.5 ). Weird thing is we donot need to clear memcached data to fix the issue, only apache restart, which would only clear the "opcache".

Comment: Which cache are you using? What version of php and cache layer?

Comment: We are using memcached and opcache ( PHP 5.5 ). Weird thing is we donot need to clear memcached data to fix the issue, only apache restart, which would only clear the "opcache"

Comment: corrupted opcache is the most common reason for this type of error so that's not surprising.

Comment: how does the "opcache" get corrupted ?

Comment: I noticed "zend_mm_heap corrupted" in the error log as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

**The error**

This error which you see means that PHP failed not at interpretation stage, but at execution stage. As you may know, PHP executes in two steps - first, compile the script into opcodes, then execute those opcodes with virtual machine (normally, that would be ZendVM). The reason because of which we can be sure that it's execution stage fail lies in [`zend_verify_arg_type()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/Zend/zend_execute.c#601), which is part of execution implementation:

```
static inline int zend_verify_arg_type(zend_function *zf, zend_uint arg_num, zval *arg, ulong fetch_type TSRMLS_DC)
{
   //I stripped some lines here (insignificant)
   if (cur_arg_info->class_name) {
      /* do the things, when typehinted is class name */
   } else if (cur_arg_info->type_hint) {
      /* your case, typehint wasn't class name */
      switch(cur_arg_info->type_hint) {
           case IS_ARRAY:
               //I stripped some lines here (insignificant)
               break;

           case IS_CALLABLE:
               //I stripped some lines here (insignificant)
               break;

           default: //<---- You error is here
               zend_error(E_ERROR, "Unknown typehint");
       }
   }
   return 1;
}
```

As you can see, for this error to occur, PHP should treat the typehint as **not a class name**, and, in the same time, as a something "unknown". That is why you cannot reproduce the error in regular case - because PHP will try to treat typehint as a class name firstly (so, error will be like *"Argument {N} passed to {function()} must be an instance of {classname}"*)

**The reason**

So, while you cannot get such error in normal execution mechanism, you still can get some corrupted compiled files - and another hint is that you're using opcache. Thus, it may be because of you're evaluating some code in your method, which can cause corrupted compilation file - but that I can not say for sure. Another thing - it may be bug, which is inside `opcache` extension. But in any case, the reason is - wrong compilation which causes such error when VM tries to execute compiled script. And, since it can be resolved by clearing opcache (so, web-server resart) - I think that a reason is - that it's a bug.

*So, TL;DR - I can not say the reason for sure, but can give some guidelines. Since this is too much for just comment, posting as an answer*

Comment: Also noticed "zend_mm_heap corrupted" corrupted in the error log. Googled it a bit but haven't noticed any concrete answers.